# Disable iBeacons in iPhone Project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

We got one of our iPhone project rejected saying iBeacons enabled.

Not sure where enabled. How to disabled ? We didnt linked CoreBluetooth.framework. We used coreLocation for push notification.

Here is rejection message from apple.

```
We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need access to a video that demonstrates your app in use.

1- We find that iBeacons is enabled, please provide a demo video to show how game interacts with iBeacons.

To provide a link to a demo video:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Scroll down to “App Review Information”
- Provide demo video access details in the “Notes” section
- Click Save
- Click Submit for Review

Once this information is available, we can continue your review.
```

Comment: Perhaps it was a misunderstanding. They might be thinking your app uses iBeacons because it only works in one location. You can reply in the resolution centre to request more info.

Comment: @BenTrengrove Thanks for your reply, it only works in one location means ?

Comment: Note that iBeacons use CoreLocation.framework, not CoreBluetooth.framework (even if it use in reality Bluetooth Low-Energy). Apple separate it giving only high-level tools. CoreBluetooth may be use to do some setting remotely to the beacons, if the firmware allow it.

Comment: @BenTrengrove Apple approved now. As you suggested we responded asking where it is used and api. Then they approved. Thanks alot for your help. That really saved my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably check you plist file. If you have required background modes as App communicates with core bluetooth & app shares data using core bluetooth kindly remove it unless you use core bluetooth framework. Tell me the background modes you use. One of my app got rejected as I used App registers for location updates for push notification functionalities that I used in my app.

Comment: yes we used CoreLocation to register push notification. Is that mistake ?

Comment: If you can provide me kindly add the required background modes in the comment. Plz update it from plist asap.

Comment: its approved now..its reviewer misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 0):

As **Ben Trengrove**  Suggested, I sent below message in resolution center

```
I asked this question in developer forum, other developer suggested this:

“Perhaps it was a misunderstanding. They might be thinking your app uses iBeacons because it only works in one location. You can reply in the resolution centre to request more info” 

Please let us know where iBeacons used in game. Which API used..give us more information.
```

Then Reviewer approved.